# Force Change of language not working in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a login screen and I have added a spinner with values hard coded in it. Based on selecting the language from spinner value, for example if I select French the activity should change into French, I have tried the code given below:

```
    package com.example.mahindras;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
 public class MahindraActivity extends Activity {
    EditText userid,pwd1;
    Button loginbut;
    Spinner langselect;
    TextView userid1;
    ResultSet rs1;
    String url="jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://10.0.2.2:1433;DatabaseName=swingmail";
    String user="sa";
    String pwd="sa";
    static  ArrayList<String> lang_spinner =  new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mahindra);
        userid1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        userid=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        pwd1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        loginbut=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        langselect=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.language);

        langselect.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String lang1=(String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                if(lang1.equals("français")){
                    String language="fr";
                    Locale locale=new Locale(language);
                    Locale.setDefault(locale);
                    Resources res=getBaseContext().getResources();
                    DisplayMetrics dm=res.getDisplayMetrics();
                    android.content.res.Configuration config=res.getConfiguration();
                    config.locale=locale;
                    res.updateConfiguration(config, dm);
                    Toast.makeText(MahindraActivity.this, "french", 10).show();
                    refresh();

                }
                if(lang1.equals("Chinese")){
                    Locale locale=new Locale("zh");
                    Locale.setDefault(locale);
                    Configuration config=new Configuration();
                    config.locale=locale;
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                }
            }

            private void refresh() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(MahindraActivity.this, MahindraActivity.class);
                    MahindraActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        loginbut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  String userid1=userid.getText().toString();
                   String pass1=pwd1.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MahindraActivity.this, "Please Wait"+userid1, 10).show();
                login(userid1,pass1);
            }

            private void login(String userid1, String pass1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String userrole1 = "";
                try{

                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
                    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
                    Statement st=con.createStatement();
                    String str="select userrole from usermaster where m_loginid='"+userid1+"'and m_password='"+pass1+"'" ;
                    String str1="select lang from language";
                    ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(str);
                    rs1=st.executeQuery(str1);
                    while(rs.next()){
                    userrole1=rs.getString(1);

                    }

                    if(userrole1.equals("admin")){
                        Intent intent=new Intent(MahindraActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                }

                    /*while(rs1.next()){
                        String langs=rs1.getString(1);
                        ArrayAdapter langadpt=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lang_spinner.add(langs));
                        langselect.setAdapter(langadpt);

                    }
                    ;*/
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_mahindra, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But the activity doesn't change with the locale language, Is my code correct or what change should I make in this program.

I have refreshed the Activity in ItemSelectedListner

```
langselect.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String lang1=(String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                if(lang1.equals("français")){
                    String language="fr";
                    Locale locale=new Locale(language);
                    Locale.setDefault(locale);
                    Resources res=getBaseContext().getResources();
                    DisplayMetrics dm=res.getDisplayMetrics();
                    android.content.res.Configuration config=res.getConfiguration();
                    config.locale=locale;
                    res.updateConfiguration(config, dm);
                    Toast.makeText(MahindraActivity.this, "french", 10).show();
                    refresh();

                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Set Your local language before set content view `setContentView(R.layout.activity_mahindra);`

Snippet from [this link](http://adrianvintu.com/blogengine/post/Force-Locale-on-Android.aspx):

```
String languageToLoad = "de";
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

Comment: if u change ur language onclick the u should have call ur activity again

Comment: Just refresh your MahindraActivity  after change local in onclick method

Comment: the Activity Refreshes but the Language doesnt change

Comment: try to restart your activity after change language

Comment: check this link http://adrianvintu.com/blogengine/post/Force-Locale-on-Android.aspx

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).